# Откуда можно тянуть результаты футбольных игр?

Tags: ajax, php, json, синтаксический-анализ

Хочу сделать сайт с результатами футбольных игр, желательно при этом иметь возможность выводить как-можно больше информации об игре (коэффициенты особо не нужны, а вот на какой минуте что произошло - было бы плюсом) и возможность выводить статистику живьем, т.е. тех игр, что идут на данный момент. И чтобы при этом была возможность использовать свои html+css шаблоны. Кто-нибудь знает, может быть есть сервисы, предоставляющие информацию? Или нужно парсить с других сайтов? На сколько я знаю сайты с результатами обычно против подхода с парсингом их статистики.

Cначала думал об http://www.livescore.in/ru/ но там похоже нельзя использовать свои шаблоны, только выводить код livescore.

Может кто подскажет оптимальное решение для данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно поможет [это](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/api_overview.php), [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370914/uefa-fifa-scores-api) и [ESPN API](http://developer.espn.com/docs/scores#using-the-api), и парсинга не надо.

Answer (score 1):

http://d.livescore.in/ru/x/feed/r_1_4

с header'ом запроса

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 1
Cache-Control   private,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  184
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 02 Aug 2014 10:21:47 GMT
Expires Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Server  Apache
Vary    accept-encoding
X-Age-BP    1
X-BPC   HIT
X-FPC   MISS
X-Signature 1a3c4a5b3f17ee37ff5808852415893d
X-VnameA    lsbproxy2/varnish1
X-VnameP    lsproxy2/varnish1
X-ttlSetA   BEH
X-ttlSetP   BEH
показать исходный код
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language *
Cookie  __utma=94122624.542439805.1406974884.1406974884.1406974884.1; __utmb=94122624.2.10.1406974884; __utmc=94122624; __utmz=94122624.1406974884.1.1.utmcsr=hashcode.ru|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/350488/php-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80
Host    d.livescore.in
Referer http://d.livescore.in/ru/x/feed/proxy
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
X-Fsign SW9D1eZo
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

дальше http://d.livescore.in/ru/x/feed/f_1_0_4_ru_4

с телом шапки

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 74
Cache-Control   private,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  31816
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 02 Aug 2014 10:21:47 GMT
Expires Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Server  Apache
Vary    accept-encoding
X-Age-BP    74
X-BPC   HIT
X-FPC   MISS
X-GeoIP RU
X-Signature 9100d75d7a6c857bd75f8c2b6701a751
X-VnameA    lsbproxy1/varnish1
X-VnameP    lsproxy9/varnish1
X-ttlSetA   BEH
X-ttlSetP   BEH
X-utime 1406974907
показать исходный код
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language *
Cookie  __utma=94122624.542439805.1406974884.1406974884.1406974884.1; __utmb=94122624.2.10.1406974884; __utmc=94122624; __utmz=94122624.1406974884.1.1.utmcsr=hashcode.ru|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/350488/php-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80
Host    d.livescore.in
Referer http://d.livescore.in/ru/x/feed/proxy
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
X-Fsign SW9D1eZo
X-GeoIP 1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
X-utime 1
```

А потом настрой крон машинку и с CURL которая будет делать туда запросы

Answer (score 1):

Парсингом страниц, и вытаскивать в вашу БД всю необходимую информацию - самый верный способ.